# Creating new object in thread, php

Tags: php, multithreading, class, object

I have a simple PHP script that produces segmentation fault. It uses PHP thread, and tries to create some simple object:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

class Dummy extends Threaded
{
    var $someVar;

    public function Dummy()
    {
        $this->$someVar = "some_value";
    }

    public function get_someVar()
    {
        return $this->someVar;
    }
}

class ThreadClass extends Thread
{
    var $arg;

    public function ThreadClass($arg)
    {
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        echo "This is arg: ".$this->arg."\n";

        $dummy = new Dummy();
        echo $dummy->get_someVar();
    }
}

$t = new ThreadClass("bla");
$t->start();
```

When I run this, I get seg fault:

```
[omer@omer Desktop]$ ./test1.php 
This is arg: bla
```

What is the problem? Can you guide me on this one. Thanks.